# Bug at pressable in React Native

Tags: react-native

im currently developing a log in system .My bug is when i press the pressable button it sends the data to the backend (node server) and recieve a correct status(so the check for the user profile is fine),but it not navigate always to the **"Home Page"** at first press.The second press make is work but not always with first press,why?

Thanks in advance.

Here are some parts of the code.

Client

```
//AXIOS request

  function getProfile(){
    try{
      axios.post('http://********/checkData',
      {
        usernameCheckAXIOS : username,
        passwordCheckAXIOS : password,
      })
      .then(function (response){
        setProfile(response.data);
      }).catch((error) => {console.log("Log In axios error" + error)})
    }
    catch(error){
      console.log("LogIn try Error" + error);
    }
  }


    
{/* Pressable for Sing In */}
        <Pressable style = {styles.pressableSignIn} onPress = {() => {getProfile(); if(profile.responseOfProfile == true)
          {navigation.navigate('Home')}}}>
          <Text style = {styles.signText}>Sign in</Text>
        </Pressable>
```

Node server

```
//Flag for user response profile
var dataProfile = {
  responseOfProfile : false,
  dataOfProfile : '',
}


//For data login - Check
app.post("/checkData",(req,res) => {

  resultOfData = req.body;
  console.log(resultOfData);

  database.query(`SELECT id,username,password,image,email from register where username='${resultOfData.usernameCheckAXIOS}' AND password='${resultOfData.passwordCheckAXIOS}'`,(reqQuery,resQuery) => {

    if(resQuery != 0){
     
      dataProfile = {
        responseOfProfile : true,
        dataOfProfile : resQuery[0],
      }

      res.send(dataProfile);

      dataProfile = {
        responseOfProfile : false,
        dataOfProfile : '',
      }

    }else{
      res.send("false");
  }});
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your code is async ([hook state doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html))

```
setProfile(response.data);
```

You could do it this way:

```
...
useEffect(() => {
   if (profile?.responseOfProfile) {
     navigation.navigate('Home')
   }
}, [profile])
...

    <Pressable style={styles.pressableSignIn} onPress = {() => getProfile())
```

Comment: Please mark your issue as solved @ThanosRom